# Flag if there was an occurrence of a value in another column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'x', 'y','w', 'x', 'z', 'z', 'y', 'w'],
                  'Flag': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]})
```

I want to add a column `b` that will flag if any entry of `a` has a flag of 1 or not:

```
a Flag b
x 1    1
x 0    1
y 0    0
w 0    1
x 1    1 
z 0    0
z 0    0
y 0    0
w 1    1
```

What I did is: groupby `a`, cumsum `Flag`, every entry that > 0 will get 1, 0 otherwise.
Is there any simpler method or function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `isin` and `.astype(int)`:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].isin(df.loc[df['Flag'].eq(1), 'a']).astype(int)
>>> df
```

---

```
   a  Flag  b
0  x     1  1
1  x     0  1
2  y     0  0
3  w     0  1
4  x     1  1
5  z     0  0
6  z     0  0
7  y     0  0
8  w     1  1
>>>
```

Or for other situations, you might need `np.where`:

```
df['b'] = np.where(df['a'].isin(df.loc[df['Flag'].eq(1), 'a']), 1, 0)
```

Comment: np.where is faster?

Comment: @SteveS I think not, but I mean a case where values might be not `1` and `0` you might have to use the `np.where` solution.

Comment: @SteveS Ah, I don't really have social media... So I don't have LinkedIn...